# Quickly & Ubuntu App Developer: Returns "State: Failed to build"

Tags: application-development, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launchpad failed to build after “quickly submitubuntu”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu)

I created an [app for the Ubuntu App Showdown](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1030/) and I'm trying to upload it to the Ubuntu Software Center.
My steps are:

1. quickly submitubuntu
2. Go to the [app page](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1030/) Ubuntu App Developer website and upload the package .tar.gz created by quickly in the step #1.
3. Then I receive this email: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1064804/

It says: "State: Failed to build". I tried to add the [libglib2.0-bin dependence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu), but I get the same result.

Any idea, please? Will be the app submit with this error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add libglib2.0-bin to the "Depends" in the binary section of debian/control, or to the Build-Depends in the source section?

It needs to be in the source (top) section in Build-Depends

Comment: Thanks. That is the problem, but quickly overwrite that file all times.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the answer from the question you referenced this is a bug in quickly that has not been fixed. Read a bit further down and do the submitubuntu steps manually as noted in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer not works for me.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1066120/
('function' user replies with the same error).